# How do I repeat letters of a string to match the length of another string?

Tags: haskell

I have a string a 'thermostat' of length 10.
I have another string "ice" of length 3.

I want to repeat letters of the second string 'ice' and form a new string to match the length of the first string.

so the expected result would look like 'iceiceicei' of length 10, same as the first string.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cycle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) to create an infinite list out of your input word, say "ice". Combine that with [take](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) and the length of the other string.

```
λ> take 10 $ cycle "ice"
"iceiceicei"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `length` as suggested in the other two answers is not ideal, because it fails for an infinite sequence. Suppose you wanted to repeat `ice` for the length of some string `s`, but `s` were defined as `repeat 'x'`? Of course, you can never "finish" this task, but the infinite string `cycle "ice"` is still a correct solution, and you can get any finite prefix of it that you want.

You can achieve this by `zip`ping two lists together, rather than basing a computation on length. This is a common technique for anytime you want to do something with two lists pairwise.

```
*Main> take 30 $ zipWith const (cycle "ice") (repeat 'x')
"iceiceiceiceiceiceiceiceiceice"
```

Expressed as a function, this would look like

```
filledWith :: [a] -> [b] -> [b]
holder `filledWith` items = zipWith const (cycle items) holder

*Main> "thermostat" `filledWith` "ice"
"iceiceicei"
```

I've used infix notation here because I think it helps remember which input determines the length and which the contents, but of course you can define and use it prefix if you prefer.

Comment: This makes sense! I was about to ask how this solves the infinite sequence problem, but then realized what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

```
rep original str = take (length original) (cycle str)

ghci> rep "thermostat" "ice"
"iceiceicei"
```